# CSS: Margin not present in the inspector but present on the page

Tags: css, margin

I have a page that is using [ng2-charts](http://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/) and the charts have a margin-right that I cannot find in the inspector. However when I scroll down and point at the margin(see screenshot) it clearly shows a right margin on the page. So there is margin but I cannot see it as a property and I cannot manipulate it.

Why?

[image]

Comment: Could you share jsfiddle?

Comment: I've seen the orange part before and I think it's not a CSS margin but something Chrome Dev Tools add to show you there will be no element to the right of it, because of `display:block;` or something similar.

Comment: @Lööri - I apologise but I cannot recreate this in jsfiddle at the moment. I'm not familiar with the way the library takes the data as we are using salesforce. I was quickly pulled just to help with the margin styling.

Comment: @Arthlete In my experience it also happens in the situation I tried to describe. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/LarsGW/5od68w1v/)'s a JSFiddle.

Comment: @LarsW - You are correct. My assumptions that it was a margin was wrong! Can you post below so I can mark your answer as the correct one to this question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems to be the Chrome Dev Tools' way of saying: the `display:block;` element doesn't occupy the full width, but there still can't be any element next to it, because of the block-display. Here's a code snippet to reproduce:

```css
div {
  width: 50%
}
```

```html
<div>Placeholder text</div>
```

Comment: Thank you!

It appears that the orange area is margin because if you scroll down in the inspector for that particular element and go to the padding/border/margin box(see screenshot in question) and point at the margin property it will highlight that area in orange. So I guess it's a defaulted margin to the right since this element's "display" is set as "block";